# Is there a way to typedef a function to modify argument in C?

Tags: c, typedef

I have code that needs to call sleep for both windows and linux.

In an attempt to avoid placing ifdefs everywhere there is a Sleep I did the following

```
typedef Sleep sleep
```

The issue with this is windows takes Sleep in microseconds and linux takes sleep in seconds. Is there a way to do something like this pseudo-code.

```
typedef Sleep(x) sleep(x/1000)
```

Comment: `typedef` is just for giving a short name to a type, it doesn't change data.

Comment: You probably want a macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot use a typedef for this purpose.

However, you can write the following [preprocessor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor) macro:

```
#if defined( _WIN32 ) || defined( _WIN64 )
#define MY_SLEEP_MACRO( x ) Sleep(x)
#else
#define MY_SLEEP_MACRO( x ) sleep((x)/1000)
#endif
```

Now, in your code, you can simply call `MY_SLEEP_MACRO( 5000 );` in order to wait 5 seconds on both platforms.

Answer (score 1):

No. `typedef` defines a new name for a type.

If you want to avoid `#ifdef`s all over the place, you can create a wrapper function that takes, say, milliseconds as its parameter, and then internally has a `#ifdef` along with any necessary conversion to seconds from milliseconds.

Comment: Actually, the name is incorrect; `typedef` does not define a new type. It defines a new name for a type. Given `typedef Anything foo; typedef Anything bar;`, `foo` and `bar` will be exactly the same type. In contrast, with `struct foo { Anything x; }` and `struct bar { Anything x; }`, `struct foo` and `struct bar` are different types and are incompatible.